# How to create a drop down to filter rows in specific columns

Tags: html, django, filter, html-table, dropdown

I have a table with over 600 rows of data. The columns headers for this table are Name, Office, Address, Primary_Role, Secondary_Role, Other_Role. I would like to create a drop down within my HTML that will have each unique role as an option and will filter through Primary_Role, Secondary_Role and Other_Role. So far I have created a drop down with each unique role as an option but I am not sure how to go about connecting it to the table so that I may get the desired outcome once an option is chosen.

HTML Code

```
<object align= middle>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="filter-group">
          <label>Desired Role</label>
          <select id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()" class="form-control" >
              <option>None</option>
              <option>Assistant</option>
              <option>Associate</option>
              <option>Compliance Officer for Finance and Administration</option>
              <option>Compliance Officer for Legal Practice</option>
              <option>Consultant</option>
              <option>Designated Partner</option>
              <option>Director</option>
              <option>Employee</option>
              <option>In-house Solicitor</option>
              <option>Locum</option>
              <option>Member</option>
              <option>Non-member Partner</option>
              <option>Partner</option>
              <option>Professional Support Lawyer</option>
              <option>Prosecutor</option>
              <option>Role not specified</option>
              <option>SRA-approved manager - Director</option>
              <option>SRA-approved manager - Member</option>
              <option>SRA-approved manager - Partner</option>
              <option>SRA-approved manager - Sole Practitioner</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <span class="filter-icon"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></span>
      </div>
    </object>
    </div>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <table id="tlaw" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Solicitor</th>
                  <th>Office</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Primary_Role</th>
                  <th>Secondary_Role</th>
                  <th>Other_Role</th>
                  <th>Other_Role_1</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tls_table">
              <tr>
                {% block content %}

                {% endblock %}
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div> 

<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("mylist");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("tlaw");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        }       
    }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After option value select pass a ajax with any method(get or post) and date or value you want to send after that update table.
or anther way is after selecting option update current url with "?key="value" and retrieve a data

Comment: I have attempted to implement your suggestion. I have failed somewhere along the way, however. When an option is selected from the drop down the entire table is cleared and will not reappear. I have updated the html code above @Gaurav Bole

Comment: Use Datatable (Ajax call)   use this example https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax